# Scientific reason behind electromagnetic induction

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-induction, induction

What actually happens inside a loop when placed in a changing magnetic field that EMF gets induced across it? And also if it is connected and the direction of the magnetic field is changed then subsequently the  direction of flow of current changes.
To sum up I would like to ask the scientific reason behind the Faraday's law.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there is any way to prove the Faraday's law of induction?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/442585/)

Answer (score 0):

When a magnetic field is changed the **ELECTRO MOTIVE FORCE** is generated in it , because. ,, when magnetic field is changed, the equilibrium of electrons are changed,, causing to experience both magnetic and electric forces and the change in the electromagnetic field, causes excitation in electrons, which makes the charge to flow across the conductor at a time, even POTENTIAL difference being generated in it, hence it causes EMF...

Answer (score -2):

https://youtu.be/MO0r930Sn_8

That is the correct answer. Feynman explains why he cannot explain why magnets attract and repel. This is a related  question.

You can either start with Maxwell's equations and mathematically prove that the emf is generated in the coil. Or you can experimentally demonstrate that it does.

Comment: Answers on SE are generally expected to be self-contained, not just references to outside sources of information. The fact that the link is to a video is an additional problem, because it's very time-consuming for people to click through and watch enough of the video to see what it's about. What Feynman says in this video is mainly philosophical, and only tangentially about magnetism. Moreover, the question he's answering about magnetism isn't the same as this question, and your summary is not IMO an accurate summary of the philosophical views he expresses.

Comment: I understand.  But from the tone if the question, that is what I thought the questioner was looking for. Why there is an emf? As I said you can either use maths or experiment